# Next 14 server side fetch shared through entire applicatiom

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

On my backend server(Express.js, localhost:3005), I have set up a passport authentication system which redirects users to the frontend(localhost:3000) and sets the cookie called token which is a jwt token. Now I am fetching this on the frontend which is next14 however I would like to do this in a context so it can be shared through the entire application, I dont wanna use next-auth as the "authenticate" function using credentials requires a post for signin but the way my backend is setup the post redirects the user to another url. The problem is that when I look on contexts online the all use "use client" as they rely on useEffect, is there a way to avoid this?

This is how I fetch my data:

```
async function getUser() {
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3005/api/user`, {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          cookie: cookieStore,
        },
      });
      
  const user = await response.json();
  return user;
}
const Nav = async() => { 
  const user = await getUser();
```